# SQL Calculations using a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds a bunch of values for an order, I can do basic calculations on it until I get to a percentage. Right now I have my query as follows

```
declare @MyNumber decimal
set @MyNumber = (select SalesTax from [OrderHeader] where OrderHeaderID = 20)

select 
    sum(o.MaterialPrice) as "MatPrice",
    sum(o.LaborPrice) as "LaborPrice",
    sum(o.MaterialCost) as "MaterialCost",
    sum(isnull(o.MaterialPrice,0)) - sum(isnull(o.MaterialCost,0)) - sum(isnull(o.LaborPrice,0)) * @MyNumber as "RESULT"
from [OrderDetail] o
inner join [OrderHeader] oh on oh.OrderHeaderID = o.OrderHeaderID
where o.OrderHeaderID = 20
```

@MyNumber is holding a SalesTax and this particular SalesTax is 7.00, I have no idea on how to convert the SalesTax to a percentage and do the calculation as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify precision and scale when declaring `decimal`, e.g.

```
declare @mynumber decimal(9,6);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YBFY72733

A simplified example:

```
select 
    convert(decimal,.07) as NotSpecified
  , convert(decimal(9,6),.07) as Specified
```

returns:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| NotSpecified | Specified |
+--------------+-----------+
|            0 | 0,070000  |
+--------------+-----------+
```

---

My best guess at what you want for your query:

```
declare @MyNumber decimal(9,6);
set @MyNumber = (select SalesTax from [OrderHeader] where OrderHeaderID = 20)

/* we want the sales tax to be a percentage (less than 1), 0.0825 */
if @MyNumber >= 1 set @MyNumber = @MyNumber *.01;

select 
    MatPrice = sum(o.MaterialPrice)
  , LaborPrice = sum(o.LaborPrice)
  , MatieralCost = sum(o.MaterialCost)
  , SubTotal = (
      sum(isnull(o.MaterialPrice,0)) 
    + sum(isnull(o.MaterialCost,0)) 
    + sum(isnull(o.LaborPrice,0))
    )
  , SalesTax = (
      sum(isnull(o.MaterialPrice,0)) 
    + sum(isnull(o.MaterialCost,0)) 
    + sum(isnull(o.LaborPrice,0))
    ) * @MyNumber
  , Total = (
      sum(isnull(o.MaterialPrice,0)) 
    + sum(isnull(o.MaterialCost,0)) 
    + sum(isnull(o.LaborPrice,0))
    ) * (@MyNumber+1)
from [OrderDetail] o
  inner join [OrderHeader] oh 
    on oh.OrderHeaderID = o.OrderHeaderID
where o.OrderHeaderID = 20
```

Comment: I marked this as correct because I understand what you are doing and can fix it to better suit what I need, the totals are off...MatPrice = 2373.35, LaborPrice = NULL, MaterialCost = 1870.18, those subtracted comes out to 503.17, and at that point the SalesTax would be multiplied by the result and the total would come out to 538.39

Comment: @Chris Yes, I wasn't sure what type of values your data held and what your business rules are. e.g. I'm not sure why only the difference between cost and sales price on materials has sales tax applied, and I'm not sure why Labor would not have sales tax applies. Also, is it possible a material to be sold at less than cost? Your sales tax would end up negative then.

Comment: That's my fault I should have explained more in detail and provided numbers in my question

Comment: @Chris As long as you got to where you are going, I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: Yes sir, and its much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by .01

```
set @MyNumber = ((select SalesTax from [OrderHeader] where OrderHeaderID = 20) * .01)
```

edit: And as SQLZim noted, you also have to specify the scale & precision when declaring a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:multiply with 0.01 for the result column

```
declare @MyNumber decimal
set @MyNumber = (select SalesTax from [OrderHeader] where OrderHeaderID = 20)

select 
    sum(o.MaterialPrice) as "MatPrice",
    sum(o.LaborPrice) as "LaborPrice",
    sum(o.MaterialCost) as "MaterialCost",
    sum(isnull(o.MaterialPrice,0)) - sum(isnull(o.MaterialCost,0)) - sum(isnull(o.LaborPrice,0)) * @MyNumber*0.01 as "RESULT"
from [OrderDetail] o
inner join [OrderHeader] oh on oh.OrderHeaderID = o.OrderHeaderID
where o.OrderHeaderID = 20
```